# Do I need to configure CUDA in my graphics card for using CUDA support in Pinnacle studio?

Tags: software-recommendation, pinnacle

The title explains a lot. Still, I wanted to ask in order to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CUDA is supported by your graphics card it should be enabled by default.

To confirm:

- Open NVIDIA Control Panel.
- Check that CUDA is enabled in global settings.

[image: global settings]

- Check Application specific settings. Make sure that Pinnacle Studio is selected in the drop down list (where I have Chrome in my example screenshot)
- Then make sure Pinncale uses global settings, or directly enable CUDA
- finally check if Pinnacle has it's own CUDA settings (I don't know about that.)
- if you have still problems, you should contact Pinnacle support

[image: program settings]